# swapped radio overlaying each other after swapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Something wrong with the event handler, as on mouse leave the div opens and closes 3 times.

also the radio that is swapped get over layed or offset.

I have tried everything, i think it has something to do with the way i am using the  event.preventDefault();

UPDATE_*_*

Menu opening 3x fixed, but the swapped radio in the div still overlaps any ideas?

http://www.apecharmony.co.uk

```
// RADIO BUTTON
$("input[name='domain_ext']").each(function () {
    $("#domaindropradio1").attr('checked', 'checked');
    var lbl = $(this).parent("label").text();
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).after("<div class='radioButtonOn'>" + lbl + "</div>");
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).after("<div class='radioButtonOff'>" + lbl + "</div>");
    }
});

$("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.radioButtonOff').add('.radioButtonOn').toggleClass('radioButtonOff radioButtonOn');
});

// RIBBON RADIO DROPBOX
$('div.ribbonBoxarrow').click(function () {
    $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').show('medium');
});
$('.ribbonBoxarrow li').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).hide('slow');
});
$("input[name='domain_ext']").parent('label').click(function () {
    $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').hide('slow');
    event.preventDefault();
});

//SWAP SECECTED RADIO
$("div.radiogroup2").on("click", ":radio", function () {
    var l = $(this).closest('label');
    var r = $('#radioselected');
    r.removeAttr('id');
    l.before(r.closest('label'));
    $(this).attr('id', 'radioselected');
    l.prependTo('.radiogroup1');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to:

> the div opens and closes 3 times.

Your animations are triggering more events than you'd like. Also, your `preventDefault()` isn't preventing other click events from firing.

For your `$("input[name='domain_ext']").parent('label')` click event, try this:

```
$("input[name='domain_ext']").parent('label').click(function () {
  $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').mouseleave();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

For your second issue:

> also the radio that is swapped get over layed or offset.

It looks like you're prepending radio buttons to an element with the `radiogroup1` class, but you may want your radio buttons to be within the nested table element.

Comment: thanks for the help was banned for asking this question will try your fix.

Comment: fixed added the     event.stopImmediatePropagation(); to the first call aswell and it worked. the swapped radio still overlaps. updated the site thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, using tables to hold elements is what was causing the problem. If it is required then you would have to target the cell for swap.